# Build Fat Jar isn't appearing in Eclipse Mars.1

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Due to a random error I encountered in Eclipse a few weeks ago, I had to reinstall it.  Prior to the reinstall I was using Juno and had added the build fat jar plugin. Since the reinstall, I've added the plug-in back into the plugin directory, and I've ran Eclipse with the `-clean` argument, but it still does not show up when I right click on a project.

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. Is there somewhere in Eclipse that I need to enable it?  Or perhaps somewhere I can at least see what Eclipse has successfully loaded?

Comment: I assume that you refer to this plug-in: http://fjep.sourceforge.net/. Since Eclipse uses p2 to manage plug-ins, you should either use the [dropins folder](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html) or install from a software repository. Did you try if the Fatjar update site http://kurucz-grafika.de/fatjar works?

Comment: To get a list of installed plug-ins go to _Help > Installation Details > Plug-ins_